# Utilizando ngCLass para actualizar clases usando los nombres de los controles

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap, typescript, bootstrap-4

Realizando unas validaciones en un formulario utilizando **Angular** para el front y bootstrap para aplicar estilos rápidos, me topé con una situación de querer aplicar cambios usando `ngClass` en el elemento **HTML** correspondiente, en este caso en inputs, realice de dos formas, una queda de manera correcta, pero afecta de forma síncrona a todos los inputs, mientras que una segunda forma que realice, funciona solo afectando al que está siendo modificado, pero no cambia las clases de manera correcta.

#### Forma 1

Creo una función que cambio el valor de la variable acorde a lo que esté en el input

**Archivo html**

```
<div class="form-group mt-2">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cedula" formControlName="Cedula" (input) = isEmpty($event)" [className]="!this.boxState ? 'form-control is-invalid' : 'form-control border border-secondary'">
</div>
```

**Archivo TS**

```
boxState: boolean = true

isEmpty(event: any){     

    if(event.target.value === ""){
        this.boxState = false
      }else{
        this.boxState = true
      } 

    })
}
```

#### Forma 2

Se me ocurrió que, pasando el nombre del control, en este caso, el `formControlName` así sabría cuál está siendo afectado, crear un objeto con los mismos nombres de los controles, luego hacer un proceso de comparar nombres, y cambiar el valor ***booleano*** acorde al nombre del control que esté cambiando.

**Archivo html**

```
<div class="form-group mt-2">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cedula" formControlName="Cedula" (input) = isEmpty($event)" [className]="!this.boxState[1] ? 'form-control is-invalid' : 'form-control border border-secondary'">
</div>
```

**Archivo TS**

```
boxState2: any = {
    Cedula: true,
    Nombre: true,
    Apellido: true,
    Telefono: true,
    Fecha_N: true,
    email: true
  }

isEmpty(event: any){

    let controlName = event.target.getAttribute('formControlName')
    let box = Object.entries(this.boxState2)

    box.forEach(box => {    

    if(event.target.value === ""){
        let position = box.indexOf(controlName)
        if(position === 0){
          box[0+1] = false
        }   
      }else{
        let position = box.indexOf(controlName)
        if(position === 0){
          box[0+1] = true
        } 
      } 

    })
    
    this.boxState = box    
  }
```

Los valores del que arroja `console.log` son los siguientes

Cuando presiono cualquier valor en el `input` del campo cédula ocurre esto

El valor de Cédula, es el nombre del control del input, y el `array`, es el objeto que cree en el fichero **TS** que lo convierto de esa forma para poderlo recorrer

[image: Controlname - object.entries]

Resultado del vector presionando un valor

[image: Presionando un valor]

Eliminando cualquier valor del campo y dejándolo vacío, pueden comparar la posición cero, como cambio de true a false

[image: sin valor alguno]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto seria mi solución, siguiendo un poco tu lógica de el segundo ejemplo.

Lo primero que no entiendo si tienes un objeto donde defines tus propiedades por que las asignas a boxstate, ya que se sobrescribirá en un segundo input cuando ingresen valores.

Lo que yo haría en tu caso, afecto directamente a boxstate2, en la propiedad que venga dentro de el target en formControlName.

Y dentro de el Html, accedo a boxstate2 en la propiedad que le corresponde según el input.

**Archivo html**

```
<input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Cedula"
        formControlName="Cedula"
        (input)="isEmpty($event)"
        [className]="!this.boxState2.Cedula ? 'form-control is-invalid' : 'form-control border border-secondary'"
      />
```

**Archivo TS**

```js
isEmpty(event: any) {
    let controlName = event.target.getAttribute("formControlName");

    if (event.target.value === "") {
      this.boxState2[controlName] = false;
    } else {
      this.boxState2[controlName] = true;
    }
  }
```

Te dejo un ejemplo funcional.

https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-lichterman-14gwl?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Muy bueno tu ejemplo, ya mismo pruebo y te digo.

Comment: Funciona perfecto, le estaba dando como dos mil vueltas, muy sencillo tu solución, gracias.